# Data view webpart customization

Tags: data-view-web-part, sharepoint-designer

I tried to customize some data view web part in SharePoint Designer 2013 but unfortunately I can't do some changes, like background color of columns or width and height of them.

What should I do? I want my web part to show like the below image for example:
[image: NewsList]

Comment: have you tried editing the webpart-settings of your webpart?

Comment: Hi Robert, do you mean from edit web part from share point site?

Comment: if you edit your page and then go to your webpart and click in the right upper edge and chose "edit webpart". there you have some layout settings.

Comment: Thank you Robert I know that but I want to customize the web part with some <table> and css for example and I don't know where can I found my columns to edit them!

Comment: I guess you can't just edit the data view webpart unless you write your own.

Comment: you can right click it and then chose something like 'inspect element' in your browser, then you know how it's built